# Distance of sets proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification, compactness

**Problem:** Let $K$ and $L$ be non-empty compact sets, and define $$d=\inf\{|x-y|:x \in K, y \in L\}$$

**(a)** If $K$ and $L$ are disjoint, show $d>0$ and that $d=|x_0-y_0|$ for some $x_0\in K$ and $y_0\in L$

***My proof:***

Let $D=\inf\{|x-y|:x \in K, y \in L\}$, we will fist show D is compact. Let $d \in D $ then $d=|x-y|$. Because $K$ and $L$ are bounded then for any $x\in K$ and $y\in L$ there exists $M_1$ and $M_2$ s.t:
$$|x|<M_1$$
$$|y|<M_2$$
therefore:
$$d=|x-y|<|x|+|y|=M_1+M_2$$
so D is bounded.

Now let $\{d_n\} \subset D$ be a convergent sequence of in D. To show D is closed we must show $d_n \to d$ for some $d\in D$. Notice $$d_n = |x_n - y_n|$$ where $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are convergent sequences in $K$ and $L$ respectively. Since  $K$ and $L$ are closed, every convergent sequence converges somewhere in that set. Hence let $(x_n) \to x$ and $(y_n) \to y$ where $x \in K$ and $y \in L$.

By the reverse triangle inequality and triangle inequality :
$$||x_n-y_n|-|x-y||<|x_n-x+y-y_n|<|x_n-x|+|y_n-y|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon $$
Hence $D$ is compact so $\inf(D)$ exists by the Axiom of completeness and $\inf(D) \in D$ therefore $d=|x_0-y_0|$ for some $x_0\in K$ and $y_0\in L$ as desired.

We will now show **$d>0$** suppose for a contradiction that $d=0$ then there would exist some $x \in K$ and $y \in L$, such that $|x-y|=0$ therefore $x=y$ but this contradicts the fact that $K$ and $L$ are disjoint.

**Why I am confused:** The next part of the problem asks me to prove the following:

(b) Show that it is possible to have $d=0$ if we assume only that the disjoint sets $K$ and $L$ are closed

**What am I confused about:** I showed that the set $D$ was closed using the fact that $K$ and $L$ were closed so I think I might have done something wrong there but I am not sure what exactly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, try $C=\{(x,1/x):x>0\}$ and the $x$-axis. I do not understand your proof, but I can offer some hints on one way to do it: in fact, prove the more general result, in which $L$ is only assumed to be closed.

$1).\ $ Set $d=\inf\{|x-y|:x \in K, y \in L\}.$ Find sequences $(x_n)\subseteq K,(y_n)\subseteq L$ such that $|x_n-y_n|\to d.$

$2).\ $ Pick a point $x_0\in K$ and $y_0\in L$ and show that

$\inf\{|x-y|:x \in K, y \in L\}=\inf\{|x-y|:x \in K, y \in L\cap \overline B(x_0,2|x_0-y_0|)\}.$

$3).\ $ There is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ that converges to some $x\in K.$

$4).\ (y_{n_k})$ is a sequence in $L\cap \overline B(x_0,2|x_0-y_0|)$, which is compact, so there is a subsequence $(y_{n_{k_l}})$ that converges to $y\in L.$

$5).\ $ Conclude that $(x_{n_{k_l}}-y_{n_{k_l}})\to (x,y)$, that $|x-y|=d$ and that $d>0.$

Remark: the slick way to do it is to note that $d:X\times X\to \mathbb R:(x,y)\mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous. Since $d(x,y)>0$ whenever $x\neq y$ and since $K\times L$ is compact, $d$ must have a strictly positive minimum on $K\times L$.

Comment: so we show the set is compact by showing that every sequence has a convergent subsequence in the set. Great I will give that a shot, thank you. Also what exactly don't you understand about my proof. I just tried to show D was compact by showing it is closed and bounded.

Comment: $d$ is a number, not a set. I do not see why you want to show it is compact.  Unless I am missing somthing obvious in your attempt. If so, apologies! Or are you considering something like this: $\{|x-y|: x\in K, y\in L\}$? In any case, in problems like these, I always draw a picture and then work from there.

Comment: Yes that is what I figured out. Your proof is fine up until you claim that "Since $K$ and $L$ are closed, every convergent sequence converges somewhere in that set." This may not be true. You need compactness to assure that this happens. And you can show this, but I think it's easier to use my approach. Anyway, the rest of your proof is fine. Glad to upvote.

Comment: Wait. How is that not true? I thought that it was a property of closed sets? Doesn't it follow from the fact that closed sets contain their limit points

Comment: btw I worked out a proof for this using your comment. Thank you very much. Also I now know what you mean. The proof is messed up because it is not necessarily the case that $x_n$ and $y_n$ are convergent sequences.

Comment: Look at counterexample at the beginning of my answer. Or just take $\mathbb R$ itself, which is closed but the sequence $(n)$ has no limit point in  $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help!

Comment: but the sequence $(n)$ is not convergent. What I was saying was that if $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence in a closed set, then its limit is in that closed set.

Comment: Yes ok. BTW all you need to do in your proof is show that $D$ as you defined it, is compact. You can so this using the compactness of $K$ and $L.$

Comment: yes, I did that thank you for the idea, you are awesome!